# How can I generate random numbers whose average follows a sine wave in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

I'm not a math guy, so I don't really know what I'm trying to do is called, but I'm sure there's a name for it. ;-)

I'm wanting to generate an array of random numbers in Ruby whose average at each element in the array follows a sine wave. What I mean by **average at each element** is the average at element `n` would be `ary[0..n].inject(:+).to_f / (n + 1)`. So, if I loop from `0..n` over the array of random numbers and generate the average like I described, I'd like the resulting values to follow a sine wave. I just don't know how to actually generate the random numbers in such a way...

```ruby
# assuming `ary` is the array of random numbers
# I'm trying to figure out how to generate...

averages = []

(0..ary.size).each do |n|
  averages << ary[0..n].inject(:+).to_f / (n + 1)
end

# `averages` should plot as a sine wave now...
```

Comment: Not sure if I got this right: Do you mean, that the averages calculated from a sliding window over your array should look like a sine wave? (Because in your code you always start from the beginning of `ary`, which will result in a straight line for larger values of `n`)

Comment: A sine wave returns to zero regularly, so I'd expect an average to be positive for half a cycle, go to zero, then be negative for half a cycle. Is that what you really mean, or are you talking about following a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)?

Comment: Matt a sliding window would be fine too, and would likely make more sense anyway. Say the last 10 elements? So... ary[-10..-1].inject(:+).to_f

Comment: Mike, ultimately I just want to generate an array of random numbers whose average at each element (whether it be a sliding window or from the beginning of the array) doesn't end up being a boring straight line when I plot the results.

Comment: In order for an average across an array of size n to change as n becomes large by adding the next item, the values (or rather their magnitudes) will need to become larger and larger - but it is do-able. A sliding window should work if the window is much smaller than the frequency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an idea.  Create a class that has some sample size over which it generates points in a sine wave plus some random "fudge factor" (variance) above or below that point.  This way, if you plot the number of points in the sample size you should see a sine wave with "roughness" according to the configured variance (fudge factor).

```ruby
class RandomSineWave
  attr_reader :size
  def initialize(size=20, variance=0.2)
    @size = size
    @step = 2 * Math::PI / size
    @position = 0
    @variance = variance
  end
  def next
    @position = 0 if @position >= 2 * Math::PI
    next_rand = Math.sin(@position) + (rand * @variance) - (@variance / 2)
    @position += @step
    next_rand
  end
end

# Generate TSV output for demonstration.
rsw = RandomSineWave.new
rsw.size.times { |i| puts [i, rsw.next].join "\t" }
```

[image: random sine wave plot]

You can fiddle with the "roughness" by modifying the second argument to the constructor:

```ruby
rsw = RandomSineWave.new(20, 0.8) # Results plotted below...
```

[image]

Comment: This is some nice code and results, but doesn't do anything about hitting targets for *average* as expressed by OP.

Comment: @NeilSlater: thanks for the feedback; I think it might be what OP is looking for since he says he wants "*an array of random numbers whose average at each element ... doesn't end up being a boring straight line when I plot the results*".  But I suppose we can let him judge...

Comment: Although if the averaging window was much smaller than `size`, then this would work for the OP's windowed variant (from the comments). He says "average at each element" (which is not well-defined, and could be taken as 'expected value' of each element or similar), but the code in the question very clearly shows an average "so far" into the array

Comment: Oh wow, thanks maerics! This looks like it will do what I was hoping for... I just wish I understood what the heck it's doing on the inside! I'll let you know if it works! I know I didn't mention this in my original post, but is there a way to specify what the max and min values should be? For example, 0 and 10, such that the wave hovers around 5? If I understood better what the code is doing I suppose I'd be able to figure this out myself... :-( Thanks again!

Comment: @Bryan: glad to hear it!  If you want to make the wave hover around 5 instead of zero just add 5 to each value it produces, or multiply by 10 to have it hover around zero but peak/valley between 10/-10.

Comment: BTW what did you use to get those nice plots?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, given some positive integer `n`, you want to construct an array of `n` probability distributions such that the expected values of partial sums of random variables describes a sine wave. I presume the sine wave is over the interval `(0..2*π)` and that the expected values are to be evenly spaced over that interval.

We must first ask if these probability distributions are statistically independent.  If they are not, it becomes hopelessly complex, so I will assume they are independent. Whether they are identical distributions, after adjusting for differences in their means, is not necessary or even important. I'll come back to that later.

Since you want the expected values of partial sums of the random variables `X`<sub>i</sub> to describe a sine wave, we require that:

E [∑<sub>j=0...i</sub>X<sub>j</sub>] = k * sin(2*π*i/n)

for all `i = 0...n-1`, for a given scale factor, `k` (with  (`E[..]` denoting "expected value"). We can assume, without loss of generality, that `k=1`, as we can always scale the random variables by `k`, resulting in their means being scaled by the same constant.

Because the distributions are independent, we can write:

∑<sub>j=0...i</sub>m<sub>j</sub> = sin(2*π*i/n)

where

m<sub>i</sub> = E[X<sub>i</sub>] is X<sub>i</sub>'s mean.

In Ruby-speak, for an array `x` of `n` values (floats), this is:

```
x[0,i].reduce(:+) = Math::sin(2.0 * Math::PI * i.to_f/n)
```

We can easily compute `x`. Assume `n = 36`.
 For `i = 0`:

```
x[0,0].reduce(:+) = Math::sin(2.0 * Math::PI * 0.0/36)
  # x[0] = 0
```

Let:

```
s = x[0]
  #=> 0.0
```

For `i = 1`:

```
x[0,1].reduce(:+) = Math::sin(2.0 * Math::PI * 1.0/36).round(6)
  #=>    0.0 + x[1] = Math::sin(0.17453292519943295).round(6) 
  #=>               = 0.173648
```

So

```
x[1] = 0.173648 - 0.0
  #=> 0.173648
```

Now let

```
s += x[1]
  #=> 0.173648
```

For `i = 2`:

```
x[0,2].reduce(:+)     = Math::sin(2.0 * Math::PI * 2.0/36).round(6)
  #=>        s + x[2] = Math::sin(0.3490658503988659).round(6) 
  #=> 0.173648 + x[2] = 0.342020
```

So

```
x[2] = 0.342020 - 0.173648
  #=> 0.168372
```

We then update `s`:

```
s += 0.168372
  #=> 0.173648 += 0.168372  
  #=> 0.342020
```

and then compute `x[3]` similarly, then each of the remaining `x`'s:

```
def compute(n, p=6)
  sum = 0.0
  n.times.map do |i|
    if i.zero?
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    else
      x = Math::sin(2.0 * Math::PI * i.to_f/n) - sum
      sum += x
      [(2.0*(i.to_f/n)*Math::PI).round(p), x.round(p),
        sum.round(p), Math::sin(sum).round(p)]
    end
  end
end

compute(36)
  #   radians    x          sum        sin(sum)    degrees
  # [[0.0,       0.0,       0.0,       0.0     ],     0
  #  [0.174533,  0.173648,  0.173648,  0.172777],
  #  ...
  #  [1.396263,  0.045115,  0.984808,  0.833166],
  #  [1.570796,  0.015192,  1.0,       0.841471],    90
  #  [1.745329, -0.015192,  0.984808,  0.833166],
  #  ...
  #  [2.967060, -0.168372,  0.173648,  0.172777],
  #  [3.141593, -0.173648,  0.0,       0.0     ],   180
  #  [3.316126, -0.173648, -0.173648, -0.172777],
  #  ...
  #  [4.537856, -0.045115, -0.984808, -0.833166],
  #  [4.712389, -0.015192, -1.0,      -0.841471],   270
  #  [4.886922,  0.015192, -0.984808, -0.833166],  
  #  ...
  #  [5.934119,  0.15798,  -0.34202,  -0.335391],
  #  [6.108652,  0.168372, -0.173648, -0.172777]]   350
```

I will add a plot of these values when I have time to familiarize myself with @maeric's nifty plotting tool.

Now that we have the means, we can consider constructing probability distributions having those means.

Suppose, for example, we assume each random variable has the same uniform distribution with range (max-min) of `rng`, for varying means. If the mean were, say, `0.325467`, we could generate a pseudo random-variate as follows:

```
rng * (rand-0.325467)
```

where

```
(0.5-0.174533).round(6)
  #=> 0.325467
```

We therefore can generate pseudo-random variates for a uniform distribution with a given range and mean as follows:

```
def uniform_rv(rng, mean)
  rng.to_f * (rand -0.5 -mean)
end
```

Comment: This is a great answer.